# LIKE operator in a function pgAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

How can I use inside a function the operator LIKE?

I have a code here in the WHERE STATEMENT that I tried the LIKE operator so that I can use this function to connect in a search bar.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.school_function(
    student text DEFAULT NULL,
    professor text DEFAULT NULL,)
    RETURNS TABLE(
    "StudentName" text, 
    "StudentID" bigint,
    "ProfessorName" text,
    "Subject" text,
    "Course" text,
)
LANGUAGE 'sql'
AS $BODY$
    SELECT "StudentName", 
    "StudentID",
    "ProfessorName",
    "Subject",
    "Course",
    FROM seniorHighTable
    WHERE ("StudentName" = ($1) OR $1 IS NULL)
    AND ("ProfessorName" LIKE ($2) OR $2 IS NULL)
$BODY$;
```

My problem is that when I use my code there is no result shown. Is there any way to use the LIKE operator inside this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to add wildcard characters to the "$2" parameter?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with postgres, but don't you need `RETURN QUERY` before `SELECT` to  return it?

Comment: @Tilin, `RETURN QUERY` is required in plpgsql language but not in sql language

Comment: sorry, i am just new in making a function. will it be possible to use a wildcard there?

Comment: @driedbananas, look at the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) and replace `LIKE ($2)` by `LIKE '*' || $2 || '*'` as stated by Culme

Comment: ...or is it `LIKE '%' || $2 || '%'` ?

Comment: thanks a lot! this worked :  LIKE '%' || $2 || '%'  thank you for the help! i really do appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing up the comments: You need to add wildcards for the LIKE statement to make it "fuzzy", otherwise it works just like an equality comparison.

The syntax for adding the wildcards involves double pipes used for string concatenation - like this:

```
WHERE ("StudentName" = ($1) OR $1 IS NULL)
AND ("ProfessorName" LIKE '%' || $2 || '%' OR $2 IS NULL)
```